# Finding a valid substring

Tags: javascript, algorithm, substring

I am a bit puzzled by one exercise I recently came across with.

It seems like an easy task and I've put my solution but it turned out it didn't pass all the tests :D

In the example, I've found two example substrings:

```
Input: S = "(()("
Output: 2
Explanation: The longest valid 
substring is "()". Length = 2.
```

and

```
Input: S = "()(())("
Output: 6
Explanation: The longest valid 
substring is "()(())". Length = 6.
```

at the first glance, everything is clear.

I came up with my solution:

```js
class Solution {

  findMaxLen(s) {
    if (!s || !s.length) throw new Error('Invalid input value provided')

    let openIndex = null
    let closingIndex = null

    for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
      if (s[i] == '(' && !openIndex) openIndex = i + 1
      if (s[i] == ')') closingIndex = i + 1
    }

    if(!closingIndex || !openIndex) throw new Error('Invalid substring')

    return closingIndex - openIndex + 1
  }
}
```

So, my solution should solve the issue of trying to find `The longest substring` with the opening and closing parentheses.

But it failed the test with an input value: `(((()`
Where the correct answer is `2` and my output is `5`

Is this `(((()` different from `()(())(` one provided in the example?

I suppose I do not wholly understand the idea of what the substring is or something...

Comment: The correct solution needs to use stack...I'm not aware of JS but I can provide a pseudocode

Comment: Thanks @vish4071 ! if you provided pseudocode it would be nice. Could you drop a few more lines on why my solution wasn't correct and what stack solves? Or maybe a link to a resource to read about it ;)

Comment: Sure, let me do that

Comment: I have posted a pseudocode. Names of vars are self-explanatory. Try and understand it and convert it to JS and test it. In the meantime, I'll post the edit to explain.

Comment: @vish4071 Explanations would help a lot! Shake your hand!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pseudocode should work. Some bugs or edge cases might have loose ends as I just wrote this here on the fly. Feel free to test it and point out the misses.

```
helper_stack = null
max_valid_len = 0
running_len = 0

for i=0 to input_s.length:
    if helper_stack.length == 0:
        if input_s[i] == ')':
            running_len = 0
            continue
        else:
            helper_stack.push('(')
    else:
        if input_s[i] == '(':
            helper_stack.push('(')
        else:
            helper_stack.pop()
            running_len += 2
            if running_len > max_valid_len:
                max_valid_len = running_len
```

### EDIT: Explanation

With your logic, you are not keeping track of order of `opening and closing` of brackets, which is important. If a `closing bracket` precedes open, string becomes invaid by default. Hence, using stack makes sense here.

If ever we encounter a closing bracket before open, we restart from that point. Hence, we set the `running_len = 0`. For every encounter of closing bracket, if an open bracket is there to balance it, we just pop it off, and since its a pair (of chars, when we consider length of string), `running_len += 2` is done.

With little modification, we can even reproduce `max_valid_substring` if needed. However, in our case, we could even use just an integer instead of `helper_stack`. For every `push('(')` operation, just do `var += 1`, and `var -= 1` for `pop` and that should also do the trick. Note that here, we are not explicitly using `stack`, but this is still conceptually `LIFO = last in first out` which is basically, stack.

Comment: So, as I can see they are both linear. But one is used with `stack` and one with `for-loop`. If you don't mind I'll come back to this quetion when I'll read more on Stacks, ok?

Comment: Actually, using stack here is not even necessary. It is the standard way, so I suggested that. Since you don't need to reproduce the longest valid substring, you can even keep track using a simple int variable. However, concept will remain same

Comment: I'm adding the explanation anyway, feel free to read it. Hopefully, you will get enough clarity @midnight_dev

Comment: Thanks! @vish4071

Comment: Do you mean they are both equel but there is just a standard way to do that using `stack`? And what about my test failure?

Comment: @midnight_dev check "Explanation". If there are still doubts, just ask :)